# ASP.NET+SQL Azure, why ExecuteReader takes much longer time?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database

I call Stored Procedure, the below command takes 200 milliseconds to return

reader1 = command1.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

but in the SP, I log time elapse, it only takes 20 milisecond to run, any idea how  can figure out what causes the extra delay?

Thanks

Comment: what is SP? And also what is Azure SQL Service tier - the Azure SQL performance is highly dependent on the service tier.

Comment: Is the Azure SQL instance located in the same region as the application?

Comment: Thanks, Steen, found that is the case, I picked west europe to test V12, Solved

Answer (score 0):

This could be several issues. Because the DUration is logged in the SP at 20 Miliseconds, my first guess would be that the issue is with network latency. 
Take a look at http://www.azurespeed.com/ to see the approximate latency for your data center. For better performance, choose the data center closest to you.